# System.IO.FileLoadException in Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop.dll The program [12796] has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'

Tags: c#

[Here the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02gr1.png)I'm using Visual Studio Code to convert a `.ifc` file to `.wexbim` but the following  exception is thrown:

> `System.IO.FileLoadException` in `Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop.dll`
>   The program '[12796] 12test.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Please post your codes

Comment: Is that the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Added the code ?